# How do I instruct Bazel to generate C/C++ assembly files?

Tags: bazel

How do I get Bazel to write out the assembly for a C/C++ program? I'd like to inspect the assembly while not having to do many changes to my current build system.

For my specific use case I need generate the assembly for all linked files when I `bazel(isk) test`. I would like to take a look at the assembly to check on some inlining behavior.

If I can't narrow the assembly generation to only occur when testing, that's fine; it's not a big deal to have to switch that on and off.

What would be nice, however, is if there is a way to control this for several compilers with one configuration (file). Hence the question is not about producing assembly with `gcc` or `clang`, but about `bazel`.

Comment: Can't be done. C/C++ doesn't exist.

Comment: And Bazel isn’t a compiler

Comment: I think the actual question is, "how do I pass additional command line options to the compiler with a Bazel makefile?"  One that is understood, then outputing via assembly becomes more clear.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It's highly unusual to need to "inspect assembly" and most of the time it can be done within a debugger.

Comment: Bazel is build system. Whatever digital artefacts you want to produce with it you need to configure toolchain (the compiling and code generating and linking etc. tools are not part of Bazel itself) for that.

Comment: Do you want assembly language files from all of your C++ or C files?  This usually requires supplying a parameter to the compiler command line.

Comment: To all of the above, (1) Bazel has the same frontend for C and C++. (2) Not sure when I referred to Bazel as a compiler. (3) I get that this needs to take place by passing a command flag to the underlying compiler. I would prefer to represent that either in the .bazelrc, a BUILD file, or the WORKSPACE file.

The handiest would be to generate them when `bazel test` is run for any sources used in the test build. I'm checking inlining behavior.

Comment: @selbie Yeah, that is the more precise way to word the question. Idk whether that makes this question more or less searchable though.

Comment: I think it's a very good question. The answer is `--save_temps`, which will emit assembly code for the targets you mention on the command line, including the helpful comments from the compiler.

Comment: @BrianSilverman Thanks! Documented here: https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual

Comment: @BrianSilverman You want to take the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[--save_temps](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#save-temps) will do this for the configured compiler.